# How can I efficiently update the metadata authority for an entire NFT collection?

Tags: metaplex, nft, authority

I need to update the authority of an NFT collection (authority on the metadata account). So when I use metaplex.nfts().update(), I need to sign a transaction for every NFT.

How can I make all updates in one transaction? thanks

Comment: I can't use metaboss because I'm making an online solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for adding the metaboss comment since this would have been my first proposal.

Doing it with signing once will not work most likely. What you could do is look what the SDK is doing to build the transaction and modify it so that

1. you can put multiple change update authority instruction into one tx
2. you can group multiple unsigned transactions into an array and then run signAll to sign all of them.

But even when doing this you would could not send all of those transactions for a 10k NFT collection at the same time to the chain.

Comment: nice thank you for your message. What do you think if I go with fetching all metadata accounts and use the solana sdk to update the authority?

Comment: Sure, that’s a valid approach!